# Wrong address returned for Index Match Max If Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to return the address of the cell with the highest score in the current period. It should be D4, but the formula returns D3.

Any ideas how to fix the formula?

> =CELL("ADDRESS";INDEX(Table6[Score];MATCH(MAX(IF(Table6[Period]=D8;Table6[Score]));Table6[Score];0)))

[image: Problem illustration]

Comment: You'll need to array enter the formula, which means confirming it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and not just Enter.  If done properly, Excel will surround the formula with curly braces {}.  (Do not add those manually)

Comment: `D4` and `D3` have the same score in your table. Because of this, Excel will default to take the first occurance of the max, and that is why it returns `D3`.

Comment: Make sure the formula accounts for the Header row.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Enter already applied, therefore you can see the {} in the formula above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to break up your calculation into two steps.  First, find the largest score for the given period using either your MAX() array function, or if you're using Excel 2016, the built in MAXIFS() function.  Next, add a new column to the beginning of your table that concatenates the date and score to create a unique ID.  Then, you can use the CELL() function with index and match on that new column.

[image]

"Largest Score":

```
=MAXIFS(Table5[Score],Table5[Period],D8)
```

"Cell Address":

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(Table5[Score],MATCH(D8&D9,Table5[Lookup ID],0),1))
```